# How to embed YouTube Sports channel

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I want to embed the YouTube auto-generated Sports channel in an iframe: http://www.youtube.com/channel/HC7Dr1BKwqctY

Somehow the regular method (http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/03/new-player-options-for-lists-of-videos.html) doesn't seem to work for this method.

Any help/alternatives are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not possible at this time. Feel free to [request this in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20%28Enhancement%20Request%29) if you'd like to see it added in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I know I can stop checking for ways to do it then.